# Outlook 2021, Cleanup & Find Duplicates

Tags: microsoft-outlook, duplicate

Hope everyone is well,

I have recently combined all my old pc backups and I have made a mess of my outlook pst data file.

I would like to get rid of all Duplicates including Duplicates that came to a different email but contain exact same subject/body as well as ideally can identify duplicates that were forwarded (I only want 1 copy of the same email ideally I can choose which "to" email to keep the single copy of any duplicate. I would be appreciative if someone could recommend the best software that will find/remove duplicates ideally freeware.

Thanks!

Comment: Right click on a folder and select Clean up Folder. Redundant messages will be moved to the Deleted folder. Stellar Tools (paid software) can repair PST files and remove duplicates to a different PST file (New PST file made and existing one kept). I do not know of any software that will delete near duplicates.

Comment: thanks for your reply, the "Clean up folder" as you say cleans redundant messages, I find this very useful if it works as it seems will delete all emails up to the very last email reply/received which contains the whole conversation. However it does not delete actual duplicates, I was subscribed to a few newsletters and had temp forwards setup that resulting in thousands of actual bit for bit duplicates but also a lot of near duplicates only difference being the "to" email or "FW:".

Comment: Cleanup will not delete near duplicates, but it will delete true duplicates. I have used Cleanup to do this. Please let me know if my comment would be a helpful comment to you.

Comment: Outlook does not handle duplicate emails by itself, you will need an add-on, to handle that action

Comment: I used the Outlook cleanup folders feature and it did not delete actual identical duplicates, it cleans up ongoing conversations leaving you with the very last which contains everything in the prior emails. I am surprised outlook 2021 doesn't include a duplicate finder, I would like to search/find all duplicates & ideally even near duplicates received by Forward or was sent to two or more of my different emails.

Comment: @JimGood - Outlook has never included a feature that finds duplicate emails. It’s not typically a problem with most Outlook users connected to a Exchange server

Comment: Outlook handles offline pst data files well the clean folder/conversation feature seems like more code/processing then a duplicate finding feature.. I combined 15+ years of pst files drag and drop into 2 now but there are literally 2-3x duplicates for every email just about even after running cleanup.. there are a bunch of 3rd party programs I'm having trouble deciding which I can trust and will work best.

Answer (score 0):

Through my research and search, I found a thread mentioned VBA script to remove the duplicate items copied and pasted manually in a specific folder. It is suggested that you could try the VBA script mentioned by ***JadeLiang-MSFT*** to check whether it is useful to you. Please refer to: [Duplicate emails in outlook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/510102/duplicate-emails-in-outlook.html#:%7E:text=Accoridng%20to%20my%20tests%2C%20it%20could%20remove%20the%20duplicate%20items%20that%20I%20copy%20and%20paste%20manually%20in%20a%20specific%20folder%2C%20so%20please%20try%20to%20press%20%22Alt%20%2B%20F11%22%20to%20paste%20the%20script%20and%20run%20it%20in%20the%20user%27s%20Outlook%20to%20check%20if%20it%20could%20also%20work%20for%20you).

Hope to help you!

Comment: while I appreciate your reply and contribution, without experience I am a bit hesitant to try a vba script that had not been tested as a trustworthy solution, the outlook cleanup function seems far more complex and more variable than a duplicate finding feature. There also seems to be dozen+ 3rd party apps that will find/remove duplicates and even near duplicates with conditions, I was hoping to get some insight/recommendations from actual users who have used any of these softwares. Thanks